# How do I replace a string that doesn't contain another string with `sed`?

Tags: ruby, sed, csv

I'm trying to replace paths in a directory.

So far, I've tried using this on every single file in the directory, however, I'm getting a syntax error:

```
sed -i \"/'#{CREW_PREFIX}'/\\\!s,/usr,#{CREW_PREFIX},g\" \${file};
```

Here's the syntax error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `u'
```

Example input:

```
prop.ppd_search_path = '/usr/share;/usr/local/share;/usr/lib;/usr/local/lib;/usr/libexec;/opt;/usr/lib64'
```

Example output:

```
prop.ppd_search_path = '/usr/local/share;/usr/local/share;/usr/local/lib;/usr/local/lib;/usr/local/libexec;/opt;/usr/local/lib64'
```

What am I doing wrong?

The line needs to match `/usr`, but it needs to not match `/usr/local`, otherwise the outputted path will be something like `/usr/local/local`.
On top of that, the replacement needs to be read from a Ruby variable,
so it could be `/usr/local` (by default), or some totally different
path like `/foo/bar`.

Use case:

There are thousands of hardcoded paths in a directory (HP Linux Printing System source code) that point to a read only path (`/usr`, in the Chrome OS case). I'm trying to replace all of the instances of `/usr` with the user-defined prefix (by default, `/usr/local`), while ignoring the line if it contains the user-defined prefix. The user-defined prefix is in a Ruby script, and it has to be contained in a Ruby variable (`#{CREW_PREFIX}`). This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  def self.patch
    # Fix hardcoded file directories
    system "for file in \$(find . -type f); do
              sed -i 's,/etc,#{CREW_PREFIX}&,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,/usr/share,#{CREW_PREFIX}/share,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,/usr/include,#{CREW_PREFIX}/include,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,/usr/lib,#{CREW_LIB_PREFIX},g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,/var,#{CREW_PREFIX}&,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,/usr/bin,#{CREW_PREFIX}/bin,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,#{CREW_PREFIX}/bin/env,/usr/bin/env,g' \${file};
              sed -i 's,#{CREW_PREFIX}/etc/os-release,/etc/os-release,g' \${file};
              sed -i \"/'#{CREW_PREFIX}'/\\\!s,/usr,#{CREW_PREFIX},g\" \${file};
            done"
  end
```

However, the path contains slashes, and that makes `sed` give an unknown command error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `u'
```

And I can't find another delimiter that contains the functionality that `/` does.

This is what I'm dealing with:

```
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/tarballs/hplip-3.19.1 $ grep -R /usr ./*/ > file; du -sh file
40K     file
```

I need all those instances of `/usr` to become the value `#{CREW_PREFIX}` (variable) if the line where the instance of `/usr` occurs does not also match the value of `#{CREW_PREFIX}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-foo --disable-bar
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-foo --disable-bar

$ var='/foo/bar'; sed 's:/usr/local:\n:g; s:/usr:'"$var"':; s:\n:/usr/local:g' file
./configure --prefix=/foo/bar --enable-foo --disable-bar
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-foo --disable-bar
```

Comment: Well, you see, it needs to be a variable. I was originally trying to use `sed`, however it needs to not include `/usr/local`. See updated question for example.

Comment: It's trivial to tweak the above to use variables but I'm sorry, I don't understand what `it needs to not include /usr/local` means. Please edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. The line needs to match `/usr`, but it needs to not match `/usr/local`, otherwise the path will be something like `/usr/local/local`. On top of that, the replacement needs to be read from a variable, so it could be `/usr/local` (by default), or some totally different path like `/foo/bar`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. You should add that to your question and make sure to include the lines you and don't want changed in your [mcve], not just the one line you do want changed. I just updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Nice. That's really close to working, except it's a directory I'm working on with thousands of files, and those files contain newlines. I will post an answer with something that worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many files there are, nor does it matter that the files contain newlines (in fact that's very much required of text files!). The script will work as-is. Add `-i` for "inplace" editing like you have in your question.

Comment: Correct, however the source code files also contain `\n`. I've already posted a new answer. If you would like me to edit yours and accept it, I could also do that.

Comment: Again, **it doesn't matter** that the source files contain `\n`s since sed is working on 1 `\n`-separated line at a time so the text sed is working on never contains `\n`s. No need to edit my answer, it's the idiomatic way to handle this and it will work as-is.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I needed multiple instances of `/usr` in the same line to also be replaced. Thanks for helping!

Comment: That sounds like it'd be no trouble at all - you should have just included that information in your question and in the example you posted so we could help you with it. You can always post a followup question now if you like.